# Retry not working in Spring Webflux with webclient

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am making a POST call which returns a **jobId** and then make a GET call using the jobId. If I get back the response as job **COMPLETED** then I need to parse the response and return it. But if the job is still **IN_PROGRESS/PENDING** then I need to retry the GET call after 1 sec.

```
The GET API response is (id=1234, eta=1000, status=IN_PROGRESS, response=null)
```

but still the GET call does not trigger a retry. How can I fix this to retry while job is in progress?

```
externalClient
            .post()
            .uri(url)
            .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.addAll(buildHeaders()))
            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(postRequest))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<Response>() {
            })
            .log()
            .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(timeout))
            .onErrorMap(ReadTimeoutException.class, ex -> handleTimeout(ex))
            .flatMap(response -> externalClient.get().uri(getLabelUri + response.getId())
                    .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.addAll(buildGetHeaders()))
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<Response>() {
                    })
                    .log()
                    .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(timeout))
                    .onErrorMap(ReadTimeoutException.class, ex -> handleTimeout(ex))
                    .flatMap(getResponse -> {
                        log.info("Get response received {}", getResponse);
                        if (!getResponse.getStatus().startsWith("COMPLETE")) {
                            return Mono.error(new RetryableException(ApiError.JOB_IN_PROGRESS,
                                    "Job is not yet completed. Job retrying again."));
                        } else {
                            log.info("Job status complete, returning response");
                            return Mono.just(getResponse);
                        }
                    })
                    .retryWhen(handleRetry(maxAttempts, backoff)));


public static RetryBackoffSpec handleRetry(Integer maxAttempts, Integer backoff) {
    log.info("Inside handle retry method");
    return Retry.backoff(maxAttempts, Duration.ofSeconds(backoff))
            .filter(RetryableException.class::isInstance)
            .onRetryExhaustedThrow((retryBackoffSpec, retrySignal) -> {
                RetryableException exception = (RetryableException) retrySignal.failure();
                return getApiException(exception.getError(), retrySignal.failure());
            });
}
```

I can see this log getting printed `Get response received (id=1234, eta=1000, status=IN_PROGRESS, response=null)`
but still the GET call does not trigger a retry. How can I fix this to retry while job is in progress?